# Calculate Radon-Nikodym derivative in a point when it is continuous in that point

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, continuity, lebesgue-integral

I can't solve the following exercise, even if I find it quite intuitive.

*Let $\nu, \mu$ be Radon measures on a metric space $(X,d)$. Suppose that:
1) $w\in L^1(X,\mu), w\geq 0$ $\mu$ a.e.; 2) $w$ is continuous in $x_0$ and $\mu(B(x_0,r))>0$ for any $r>0$; 3) $\nu(A)=\int_Aw d\mu$ for any $A\in \mathcal M$.*

*Show that there exists $$\lim_{r\to 0} {\nu(B(x_0,r))\over \mu(B(x_0,r))}=w(x_0).$$*

We know that $$\lim_{r\to 0} {\nu(B(x_0,r))\over \mu(B(x_0,r))}=w(x_0) \iff \lim_{r\to 0} {\nu(B(x_0,r))\over \mu(B(x_0,r))}-w(x_0)=0$$ and $$\lim_{r\to 0} {\nu(B(x_0,r))\over \mu(B(x_0,r))}-w(x_0)=0 \iff \lim_{j\to \infty} {\nu(B(x_0,r_j))\over \mu(B(x_0,r_j))}-w(x_0)=0 ,$$ for any sequence $r_j\rightarrow 0$.

So I've thought to prove the latter one. Let $a_j={\nu(B(x_0,r_j))\over \mu(B(x_0,r_j))}-w(x_0)$ for any $j$, so I have to prove that (*) $\forall \epsilon>0 \exists N\in \Bbb N: j>j_N \implies |a_j|<\epsilon.$

Thus, let $\epsilon>0$ be given.
Since $w$ is continuous in $x_0$ we have that  $\exists N\in \Bbb N: j>j_N \implies |w(x_j)-w(x_0)|<\epsilon$ for any sequence $x_j\rightarrow x_0$.

And now? I don't know if this is the right approach to solve this exercise and, also if it were, I've lost myself in all this limits!

Can someone help me?

Comment: State the continuity of $w$ in $x_0$ not using sequences converging to $x_0$, but with the $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ definition: $$\bigl(\forall \varepsilon > 0\bigr)\bigl(\exists \delta > 0\bigr) \dotsc$$

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

$$ \frac{\int w(x) d\mu}{\mu(B(x_{0},r))} - w(x_{0}) = \frac{\int w(x) d\mu}{\mu(B(x_{0},r))} - \frac{\int w(x_{0}) d\mu}{\mu(B(x_{0},r))} = \frac{\int (w(x)- w(x_{0})) d\mu}{\mu(B(x_{0},r))}$$

Comment: Ok, so should I try to prove that $\forall \epsilon \exists \delta: x\in B(0,\delta) \implies {|\int(w(x)-w(x_0))d\mu|\over \mu(B(x_0,r))} <\epsilon$?

Comment: Could you tell me if the following is correct? Fix $\epsilon$, then $${|\int (w(x)-w(x_0))d\mu| \over \mu(B(x_0,r))}\leq {\int |w(x)-w(x_0)|d\mu \over \mu(B(x_0,r))};$$ since $w$ is continuous, there exists $\delta$ such that $|w(x)-w(x_0)|<\epsilon$ if $x\in B(x_0,\delta)$. Thus ${\int |w(x)-w(x_0)|d\mu \over \mu(B(x_0,r))}<\epsilon$. And this concludes the proof.

Comment: I'm sorry Vishal, I can't find the mistake. I think that the problem is that $|w(x)-w(x_0)|<\epsilon$ only for those $x\in B(x_0,\delta)$.

Comment: @Claretta Actually, you are right. I made that minor mistake! Your proof is spot on now.